# Compiler issue with npm React package-lock.json "autoprefixer" version 9.8.1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, autoprefixer, package-lock.json

Just installed React `npx create-react-app client` and it failed to compile when launched citing the error `...autoprefixer/node_modules/kleur' do not define a valid './colors' target`. I re-installed, it launched, but it failed again when launched concurrently with the express server.

Digging further... Kleur (version 4.0.1) is a dependency for "autoprefixer" in the package-lock.json file (version 9.8.1). I noticed that yarn.lock is referencing kleur version 3.0.3, though version 4.0.1 was installed in node_modules. A few days earlier, I had installed a React client where "autoprefixer" (version 9.8.0) used "chalk" with no "kleur" dependency, and which had no problems starting up.

Though not really understanding the problem, I replaced the "autoprefixer" code snippet (v. 9.8.1) in the newly installed client package-lock.json file with the previously installed version (9.8.0) and it appears to have solved the compiler issue. Curiously, references to kleur@^4.0.1 in node_modules seemed to switch to kleur@^3.0.3 after I made the change, which I cannot explain.

Thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of investigation, I found the problem. The problem was in the `autoprefixer.js` file which is part of dependencies in node_modules. As I understood system couldn't find the address of `Kleur` module. Just go to this file in the following path:

```
node_modules > autoprefixer > lib > autoprefixer.js
```

in this file change the value of `kleur` variable from :

```
var kleur = require('kleur/colors');
```

to

```
var kleur = require('../node_modules/kleur/colors');
```

I found this by comparing the address of this module with other modules in same file. if you hover your mouse on other modules like `postcss` you can see it has a complete address but this module `kleur` doesn't have such an address so when I changed the address to new value now it shows full address like other modules and it worked for me.